# Bootstrap Modal not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a simple button that uses bootstrap's modal, which is like a popup div.  I can't get it to work.  When i click the button, nothing happens.  Im using firefox. I'm probably forgetting something simple, but i can't find the problem.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">

     </head>
     <body>

      <a class="btn" data-controls-modal="my-modal" data-backdrop="static" id='mod'>Launch Modal</a>

     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"  ></div>
  <div class="modal hide fade in" id="my-modal" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn primary" href="#">Primary</a>
        <a class="btn secondary" href="#">Secondary</a>
    </div>
```

You have to put this code in your page body which is the html code of the pop-up(modal).
Less file used for this code is patterns.less. and  my-modal is the id of the pop-up

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I think you don't need div of class modal-backdrop. It's added by bootstrap javascript while showing modal.

Comment: Is it possible you could expand this answer to show how the Primary and Secondary buttons can be wired up to actually do something.  Say, primary should open page 'foo.html' and secondary should open page 'bar.html'

Comment: I am not expert but I think we can use the href to link 'foo.html' or any resp file or also can use javascript or jquery function to get this work.

Comment: there's no need to put `display:none` . `hide` class takes care of that

Answer (score 6):

also, make sure you include the css rules to style the backdrop elemen. For example:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```